# TypeScript DefinitelyTyped Nuget package won't take effect before doing some file changes

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, nuget

Every time I install a DefinitelyTyped Nuget package, I have to rename the path (or maybe other file changes) so that the definitions would take effect project wide.

Anyway to make it feel better?

I am now using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

Comment: Which path do you have to rename?

Comment: @Monsingor Usually I would rename the declaration folder under ```typings``` and then rename it back. Recently I noticed that refresh the project tree would also work.